# How use Locator for planar point and image of that point under a function?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, dynamic

Consider the following function as mapping the `{x,y}`-plane to a copy of that plane:

```
F[{x_, y_}] := {x^2 - y^2, 2 x y}
```

I want to visualize what that mapping does to a particular point against a background of a rectangular grid in the domain and the image point under `F` of that grid in the image plane.

Making a static visualization for a particular point is straightforward:

```
With[{pt = {1, 1}},
  domStatic = Show[{
    ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
      Mesh -> {5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1, Lighter@Yellow]], 
    Graphics[{PointSize@Large, Red, Point[pt]}]},
    Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.3]];
 imageStatic = Show[{
   ParametricPlot[F[{x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
     Mesh -> {5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1, Lighter@Yellow]], 
   Graphics[{PointSize@Large, Red, Point[F[pt]]}]},
   Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.3]];
Row[{domStatic, Spacer[10], imageStatic}]
]
```

[image: Static picture of mapping F]

Now I want to make the domain point `pt` dynamic and have the image `F[pt]` under `F` of that point move accordingly as the `pt` is moved.

This is easy using a 2D-slider. First make the domain and image graphics depend on the point as an argument...

```
Clear[pt, dom, image]
dom[pt_] := Show[{
    ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
     Mesh -> {5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1, Lighter@Yellow]], 
    Graphics[{PointSize@Large, Red, Point[pt]}]},
   Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.3]];
image[pt_] := Show[{
    ParametricPlot[F[{x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
     Mesh -> {5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1, Lighter@Yellow]], 
    Graphics[{PointSize@Large, Red, Point[F[pt]]}]},
   Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.3]];
```

... and then use `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
  Row[{dom[pt], Spacer[10], image[pt]}],
  {{pt, {1, 1}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}}
]
```

[image: Dynamic picture of F with 2D-slider]

**Question:** How can I produce such a dynamic visualization but by using a `Locator` for the point in the domain (instead of a 2D-slider)?

The following does *not* work: it puts the `Locator` in the image plane instead of in the domain plane!

What's wrong and how can it be fixed?

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{dom[pt], Spacer[10], image[pt]}],
 {{pt, {1, 1}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image: Error: dynamic picture of F with Locator]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your F:

```
F[{x_, y_}] := {x^2 - y^2, 2 x y}
```

Let's generate static background images:

```
backgroundDomain = 
  ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    Mesh -> {5, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1, Lighter@Yellow], 
    Frame -> False, 
    ImageSize -> 300];
backgroundImage = 
  ParametricPlot[F[{x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    Mesh -> {5, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1, Lighter@Yellow], Frame -> False, 
    ImageSize -> 300];
```

Now let's create a display:

```
Row[
  {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], backgroundDomain], 
   Dynamic[Show[{backgroundImage, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[F[pt]]}]}]]}]
```

Is that what you're after? Might want to parameterize the background images, with size for example.

**Edit**

You can change the appearance of the Locator with the Appearance option. For example,

```
LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[pt], 
  backgroundDomain, 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 10]]
```

Comment: That does display what I want, but I was hoping there was a way to do it in a `Manipulate` (where the backgrounds could be set inside an  `Initialization`.

Answer (score 5):

We use `pts = RegionNearest[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]]@pts;` to limit the point to the `Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]`.

```
F[{x_, y_}] = {x^2 - y^2, 2 x y};
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {5, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1, Lighter@Yellow], Frame -> False, 
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   ParametricPlot[F@{x, y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {5, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1, Lighter@Yellow], 
    Epilog -> {PointSize@Large, Red, Point[Dynamic@F@pt]}, 
    Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Medium, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
   }], 
   {{pt, {0, 0}}, Locator, TrackingFunction -> 
   Function[pos, pt = RegionNearest[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]]@pos],
   Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{0, 0}]}]
   }
]
```

[image]

Comment: I've made your code work more smoothly, hope you don't mind, you can update the gif if you want.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you very much, I learn more from the new edition. I will updated the gif later.

Comment: @cvgmt: this does not seem to work if I change `ImageSize -> Medium` to `ImageSize -> Scaled[0.4]`, say. Then the locator appears inside the right-haind oval!

Comment: @cvgmt: How did you produce for your answer an animated gif from the Manipulate?

Comment: @murray I am using ScreenToGif https://www.screentogif.com/

Comment: @cvgmt: Drat: ScreenToGif seems to be strictly for Windows; i'm on a Mac.